# Doctrine findBy where and order

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I have a snippet on symfony doctrine that picks data in descending order. Attempting to Apply a where clause some fields it equal to true is a problem. Below is my snippet

```
$results = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('RealBundle:Foo')->findBy([], ['id' => 'DESC','active' => true]);
```

I have a field called active. Retrieving all the results where active is equalto true is a challenge

The above attempt gives an error

> Invalid order by orientation specified for 
>    RealBundle\Entity\Foo#active

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The first parameter is the WHERE clause, the second parameter is the ORDER.

```
$results = $this
  ->getDoctrine()
  ->getRepository('RealBundle:Foo')
  ->findBy(['active'=>true], ['id' => 'DESC']);
```

`findBy` signature as described in [the documentation](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/working-with-objects.html#by-simple-conditions)

```
findBy(array $criteria, array $orderBy = null, $limit = null, $offset = null)
```

Answer (score 2):

try this

```php
$results = $doctrine->getRepository(Task::class)
            ->findBy(['active'=>true], ['id' => 'DESC']);
```